# How does torch.empty calculate the values?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch

Every time I run `torch.empty(5, 3)` I get one of those two results:

```
>>> torch.empty(5, 3)
tensor([[     0.0000,      0.0000,      0.0000],
        [     0.0000,      0.0000,      0.0000],
        [     0.0000,      0.0000,      0.0000],
        [     0.0000,     -0.0000,      0.0000],
        [     0.0000,      0.0000, -50716.6250]])
>>> torch.empty(5, 3) 
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]])
```

I tried this multiple times and I still get one of those two results. I tried changing the size number `-50716.6250` appeared again.

Are the values here random? Why are those numbers reoccurring?

Comment: AFAIK when using `empty` pytorch just allocates memory space for the array but does not initialize the values in this space, you get whatever values are set to those cells in the memory.

Comment: This explains why this number kept on appearing. Thanks!

Comment: my torch.empty changes values on each run. I am running this in jupyter lab. Any ideas on why?

Answer (score 4):

[`torch.empty`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.empty) returns "a tensor filled with uninitialized data."

If you want to have a tensor filled with zeros, use [`torch.zeros`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.zeros).

Comment: You’re right but I was just wondering how I’m getting those values in the tensors. They’re clearly not random and some values where reappearing consistently.

Comment: They are surely not random. PyTorch will probably allocate a space in memory without changing its contents. When the same number reapers it means you are getting the same memory space.